# Can Ping but Cannot Telnet directly to SQL Server 2012 Cluster Nodes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, monitoring

We have a monitoring tool (Solarwinds Orion) that needs to connect to a 2-node failover SQL Server Cluster.  For reasons outside of our control -- we cannot monitor the CLUSTER IP directly at this time, so we have fallen back to monitoring each cluster node IP directly.  This is not working.  Upon troubleshooting, we tried to test that the cluster node was listening on the proper (fixed) port by using telnet to the cluster node IP/port -- and the telnet failed.  However, telnet'ing to the Cluster IP/Port was SUCCESSFUL!

- Each node has its own IP.
- Each node is listening on the identical FIXED port.
- Each node has Dynamic Ports disabled.
- Each node can be PINGED successfully from the monitoring tool.
- Windows Firewall is DISABLED.

How can I troubleshoot why I cannot telnet to the listening port on the cluster nodes?

Comment: Any router or firewall in between Orion and the servers that may have ACL's blocking the connection (this would assume that it has a rule allowing the connection to the cluster IP)?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issues when the cluster was configured http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn376546.aspx - Azure version , SQL 2012 Availibility groups http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff877884.aspx . Please make sure that you have the correct listeners and firewall settings .